# CoffeeScript Confusion? (KeyUp Jquery)

Tags: coffeescript

I've just started using coffeescript to see what all the fuss is about and I love it. However there is a problem I had when converting an old script of mine over to coffee:

```
$(function() {
    $(create_MP).keyup(function(e){
        if(e.which == 16) {
            isShift = false;
        }
    });
});
```

That's the JQuery that I had before so I tried to transform it into coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->
    $(create_MP).keyup(e) ->
        if e.which == 16
            isShift = false
```

But I get this error when opening the console:

`application.js:23Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'keyUp'`

Any ideas?

Comment: Woops! My stupid mistake. I had typed keyUp instead of keyup further along in the script. :)

Answer (score 8):

That code is wrong regardless. The CoffeeScript you posted is equivalent to this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $(create_MP).keyup(e)(function() {
        if (e.which == 16) {
            isShift = false
        }
    }
}
```

That is, you're calling the result of `keyup(e)` and passing a function to it. What you want is to call `keyup()` with the function as an argument. The simplest way to fix it would just to put a space between `keyup` and `(e) ->`.

```
jQuery ->
  $(create_MP).keyup (e) ->
    isShift = false if e.which is 16
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem you note in your comment isn't your only problem. You need to a space before `(e)` or CoffeeScript will think you're trying to call the `keyup` function with an argument of `e`. You want to say this:

```
jQuery ->
    $(create_MP).keyup (e) ->
        if e.which == 16
            isShift = false
```

Without the space, your JavaScript will look like this:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $(create_MP).keyup(e)(function() {
    // ...
```

and that doesn't make any sense since `keyup(e)` won't return a function. But, if you add the space, then `(e) ->` becomes a definition of an anonymous function which takes a single `e` argument:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $(create_MP).keyup(function(e) {
    // ...
```

and not only does that make sense, it does what you want it to do as well.